# Why is my data from my Socket.io disconnect event different

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a web app I am trying to build using Socket.io to update pages in real-time based on what other users are doing. I believe I either have a fundamental misunderstanding of how I should be using Socket.io or I have a simple error I can't see myself.

Every time a user loads the page they will connect to a 'lobby' room, they also are able to create their own custom rooms that other users can join.

On the server side I have a map that stores the rooms that are currently open, excluding the lobby and each user's private room to themselves. I have functions to handle placing a user in a specific room, and remove a user from a room and these functions have been tested and work as intended.

If I place this remove user function in an event other than disconnect it works and the user is removed from the custom room and placed into the lobby however, once the function is called in the disconnect event the data isn't logging the same.

Custom event that works currently, I can press 'e' to trigger a window event from the client that emits this 'roomexit' event and the following code does remove them from the map of rooms and even deletes the room if they were the last person in it.

```
const onRoomExit = (socket, roomList) => {
    // socket is the socket being received by the server
    // roomList is the map
  socket.on("roomexit", () => {
    let roomName;
    socket.rooms.forEach((rn) => {
      if (rn !== socket.id && rn !== "lobby") {
        roomName = rn;
      }
    });
    if (!roomName) {
      return;
    }
    roomList.get(roomName).players.removePlayer(socket.id);
    if (roomList.get(roomName).players.size === 0) {
      roomList.delete(roomName);
    }
  });
};
```

roomList is a custom class that extends a built-in Map and contains this method:

```
findRoomName(id) {
    this.forEach((val, key) => {
      console.log(val.players.has(id));
      if (val.players.has(id)) {
        return val.name;
      }
    });
    return null;
  }
```

I have tested this function and it works, when called in the 'roomexit' event it logs the correct information which is the name of the room the socket is connected to by checking the roomList map.

But when I call this function in the disconnect event it logs null every time.

```
const disconnectHandler = (socket, roomList) => {
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log(roomList, socket.id);
    console.log(roomList.findRoomName(socket.id));
  });
};
```

Here is what the console is outputting:

[image: console output]

Connect event fires, on disconnect it logs the roomList which shows the created room and the id of the user in the room, then the true statement is coming from within the function findRoomName, and then finally the null is coming from the disconnect event again.

I am not sure if it's a problem of needing to handle this function in an asynchronous way but I didn't think that was necessary since I'm only updating local information stored on the server.

For some reason it works when I place the code from the function directly into the disconnect event, is there any reason why my code from my function isn't working when called?

```
socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    roomList.forEach((val, key) => {
      if (val.players.has(socket.id)) {
        let roomName = val.name;
        roomList.get(roomName).players.removePlayer(socket.id);
        if (roomList.get(roomName).players.size === 0) {
          roomList.delete(roomName);
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: You can't return from `forEach`. Stop using this function and start using regular for loops. There's no reason to _ever_ use `forEach`.

Comment: @Evert Okay interesting. I can refactor to remove the forEach loops and use For in loops, it's a Map so a regular for loop doesn't work. I didn't know about not being able to return from a forEach loop, knowing that now I can change that behavior in the future, thanks!

Comment: also don't use `for( ... in ..)`. The loop you're looking for is `for(const x of arr)`

Answer (score 0):

You can't return from forEach. Stop using this function and start using regular for loops. There's no reason to ever use forEach. - @Evert

Question answered.